# Duodecimal Recursive Convert an Integer to a String

Tags: java, recursion

I have no idea how to assign a String value a number and make it automatically recognize to make the number a String value. The problem goes as follows:

To write the method recursively:
1) consider the base case of returning just the number itself when it is less than 12 (the quotient will be 0 when dividing by 12 and the remainder is the number).  return "A" or "B" if the number is 10 or 11.

2) consider the recursive case of the number greater than or equal to 12.  In this case, first call the method recursively using the quotient and concatenate the result (use the + operator to connect the Strings) with the result of another recursive call using the remainder.  Return the concatenated result of the two recursive calls.

An example; 20A would be:

2 x 12^2 + 0 x 12^1 + 10 x 12^0 = 2 x 144 + 0 x 12 + 10 x 1 = 288 + 0 + 10 = 298

*I know the code is completely wrong right now*

```
public class Duodecimal {
  public static String toBase12(int n) {
    //TODO: complete this method
    if (n==10)
    return "A";
    if (n==11)
    return "B";
    if (n<12)
    return n;
    else {
      if (n%12==10)
      return (n/12 + "A");
      if (n%12==11)
      return (n/12 + "B");
      else
      return n/12;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"return "A" or "B" if the number is 10 or 11"* which means that A=10 and B=11, so why is `20A` using `1 x 12^0`, when it should be `10 x 12^0`?

Comment: Minor but 20A would be 2x12^2 +0x12^1 + 10x12^0 = 2x144 + 0x12 + 10x1 = 288 + 0 + 10 = 298

Comment: I suggest trying something like this - take the input N and compute N/12 and N%12.  Then prepend string value of N%12 and recurse (tail recursion) on value of N/12.

Comment: *"consider the recursive case of the number greater than or equal to 12. In this case, **first call the method recursively** using the quotient"* I see no attempt at doing that in the `else` block.

Comment: *Typo Fixed* Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got #1 done almost correctly (`return n` fails to compile), so let's look at #2:

> consider the recursive case of the number greater than or equal to 12. In this case, first call the method recursively using the quotient and concatenate the result (use the + operator to connect the Strings) with the result of another recursive call using the remainder. Return the concatenated result of the two recursive calls.

Let's take it one step at a time, working on the bold part.

> first call the method recursively **using the quotient**

```
int quotient = n / 12;
```

> first **call the method recursively** using the quotient

```
toBase12(quotient)
```

> result of another recursive call **using the remainder**

```
int remainder = n % 12
```

> result of another **recursive call** using the remainder

```
toBase12(remainder)
```

> [...] and **concatenate** the result (use the + operator to connect the Strings) with the [...]

```
toBase12(quotient) + toBase12(remainder)
```

> **Return** the concatenated result of the two recursive calls

Let's eliminate the variables too:

```
return toBase12(n / 12) + toBase12(n % 12)
```

As you can see, the assignment included step-by-step instructions of what you should do. All you had to do was write the code is explained to you.

The final result is:

```
public static String toBase12(int n) {
    if (n < 10)
        return Integer.toString(n); // or  String.valueOf(n)  or  "" + n
    if (n == 10)
        return "A";
    if (n == 11)
        return "B";
    return toBase12(n / 12) + toBase12(n % 12);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(toBase12(298));
```

*Output*

```
20A
```

Comment: Thanks! Very well done explanation. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

On a piece of paper, you'd go this way:

1. Divide the input by twelve and save the remainder.
2. Divide the result again by twelve and save the remainder.
3. continue with step two until the result is zero. Concatenate the
   remainders from each step from bottom to top.

With your example input:

```
298 / 12 = 24 rem 10 (A)
 24 / 12 = 2  rem 0
  2 / 12 = 0  rem 2
```

Therfore

```
298 in base 10 = 20A in base 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with tail recursion.  The second method accumulates until you get down to zero then returns.

```
public class Base12 {
    public static String toBase12(int n) {
        return toBase12(n, "");
    }

    private static String toBase12(int n, String value) {
        return n <= 0 ? value : toBase12(n/12, toBase12Char(n%12) + value);
    }

    private static char toBase12Char(int n) {
        return n == 11 ? 'B' : (n == 10 ? 'A' : Integer.toString(n).charAt(0));
    }
}

public class Base12Test {
    @Test
    public void Test20A() {
        int n = 298;

        String expectedValue = "20A";
        String actualValue = Base12.toBase12(n);

        Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
    }
}
```